# Mongoose unique keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a database for my login purposes contains `loginid`, `username`, `password` etc. How do I define that my `usernames`, `loginids` and `passwords` are unique in the *MongoDB*? That means no duplicates are allowed to be created. Here is some code I use:

```
app.post('/api/register', async function (req, res){
  try  {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
    console.log(hashedPassword);
    console.log(await bcrypt.compare('testtest',hashedPassword));
    var user = new User({ loginId: req.body.id, firstname: req.body.username, password: hashedPassword });
    user.save(function (err, User) {
      if (err) return console.error(err);
      console.log("Saved successfully");
    });
    jwt2.sign({user}, 'secrethere', { expiresIn: '15min'}, (err, token) =>{
    res.json({
      token
    });
  });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send()
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

**My user.js:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    loginId: String,
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    eMail: String,
    password: String,
    active: Boolean
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unique: true` option in mongoose schema definition.This option creates an [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) on the field.

Making password field unique may not a good idea.

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  active: Boolean
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

This will cause an error like this when a duplicate loginId is being tried to insert:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key
>   error collection: ....

This `unique: true` option is supposed to create an unique index.

But it does not create, you can manually create using the following script:

```
db.users.createIndex( { "email": 1 }, { unique: true } );
db.users.createIndex( { "username": 1 }, { unique: true } );
```

I also refactored your register route like this:

```
app.post("/api/register", async (req, res) => {
  const { username, email, password, firstname, lastname } = req.body;

  let user = new User({ username, email, password, firstname, lastname });

  try {
    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10);
    user = await user.save();

    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        _id: user._id,
        username: user.username,
        email: user.email,
        firstname: user.firstname,
        lastname: user.lastname
      },
      "secrethere",
      { expiresIn: "15min" }
    );

    res.json({
      token
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
});
```

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work, I don't get any error message and there's now multiple John Does with loginId 4 and same e-Mail in the MongoDB

Comment: @Munchkin  which solution did you try?

Comment: the first one: `loginId: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
    },
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    eMail: { 
    type: String, 
    unique: true 
    }, 
    password: String,
    active: Boolean
`

Comment: @Munchkin  can you check if your User collection has unique index created?

Comment: the _id is different in every document. if you want me to check the id of every key somehow I don't know how to do that

Comment: @Munchkin is it possible to drop your User collection, and then create new users? You may need to create a backup of your users if it is important.

Comment: I dropped the users collection from the db and it still does not throw an error when it violates the uniqueniness rule

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203574/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-munchkin).